# How to draw scruffy diagrams in R?

Tags: r, plot

Any ideas how to do "scruffy" bar and scatter plots (like [yuml](http://yuml.me/diagram/scruffy/class/draw)) in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have in mind the exact replicate of the sample graph on the link that you have provided... well, let's say that you have very slim chances of success...

But I recall an article in `The R Journal Vol. 1/1, May 2009`, written by THE ***Paul Murrell*** - *Drawing Diagrams with R*. Murrell suggests two packages: `shape` and `diagram`.

I haven't done any diagram in **R** so far - I prefer `Dia` application available on Linux platforms (and there are ports for MacOS and Windows). Murrell's article is concentrated on low-level graphing capabilities, so it's very flexible, but on the other hand a bit labour-intensive... I'm sure that learning effort pays off in the end, but I usually need something quick, so I use `Dia`.

Comment: I don't want to replicate UML-diagrams in R, what I like to replicate is the way the boxes are layed out there -- they look as if they were drawn by hand.

Comment: There is the new support in R 2.11.0 for raster images, it might be of use here:  http://developer.r-project.org/Raster/raster-RFC.html

Comment: As I said... no luck there! Maybe you can export graph as SVG, hence edit it in Inkscape, Corel, or so... Or you can write a script to submit form based on R data? Hmm... not bad idea... if you know how to do it with `RCurl`, you're kicking!

Comment: I think I will try the SVG and postprocess route when I have some time.. Thanks for the input!